# how to append a FOR loop value into a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, append

Hello I am trying to append a value into a list and although there are various examples of this on here this is different I am using a FOR loop to go through all of the values into a list and if the right name is found in "each" I want to append "each" into a new list. Here is an example

```
for each in lines:
            if names in each:
                print(names)
                print(each)
                if len(newnames)<=3:                   
                    newnames.append((each))

                elif len(newnames)>3:                
                    newnames = newnames[:2]
            print(newnames)
```

lines looks like this

['alex|7', 'jake|10', 'jake|2', 'jake|5', 'josh|3', 'josh|5', 'josh|7', 'megan|6', 'megan|8', 'megan|9']

Names is just a list with only one copy of each of these names. Hope this is enough information for you to be able to work out an answer because it has me completely stumped.

Cheers.

Comment: output is this:- `['alex', 'jake',  'josh',  'megan']` ??

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Names is = ['alex', 'jake', 'josh', 'megan']

Answer (score 0):

If you want only names from the lines and use string split() method to split name from the lines items.

e.g.

```
>>> names = set()
>>> l = ['alex|7', 'jake|10', 'jake|2', 'jake|5', 'josh|3', 'josh|5', 'josh|7', 'megan|6', 'megan|8', 'megan|9']
>>> for i in l:
...     names.add(i.split("|")[0])
... 
>>> print names
set(['josh', 'jake', 'alex', 'megan'])
>>>
```

Pythonic way:

```
>>> l = ['alex|7', 'jake|10', 'jake|2', 'jake|5', 'josh|3', 'josh|5', 'josh|7', 'megan|6', 'megan|8', 'megan|9']
>>> set([i.split("|")[0] for i in l])
set(['josh', 'jake', 'alex', 'megan'])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question entirely, but if I did, then what you want to do is parse the strings in your lines list, and then check whether the parsed name occurs in your names list. If so, you want to append it to a new list.

If you want the list to be unique, simply replace it with a set (and the append with add), or alternatively add `result = set(result)` to the end of the program.

Anyway, how about:

```
result = []
for each in lines:
    name = each.split('|')[0]
    if name in names:
        result.append(name)
print result
```

Given your input list, this will give as result:

```
['alex', 'jake', 'jake', 'jake', 'josh', 'josh', 'josh', 'megan', 'megan', 'megan']
```

If all those names are in your `names` list. If not, it will only append those names that are in that list.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vivek and also I think that:

```
    if names in each:
```

should be

```
    if each in names:
```

It also appears as though you are comparing a list to an element of a list. Normally you perform the opposite comparison. You also do not need to append the value as a tuple, you can simply append to the list. See this example:

```
    lines=['alex|7', 'jake|10', 'jake|2', 'jake|5', 'josh|3', 'josh|5', 'josh|7', 'megan|6', 'megan|8', 'megan|9']
    names=[l.split('|')[0] for l in ['alex|7', 'jake|10', 'jake|2', 'jake|5', 'josh|3', 'josh|5', 'josh|7', 'megan|6', 'megan|8', 'megan|9']][:-4]
    newnames=[]

    for each in [l.split('|')[0] for l in lines]:
        if each in names:
            print(names)
            print(each)
            if len(newnames)<=3:   
                newnames.append(each)

            elif len(newnames)>3:
                newnames = newnames[:2]
                print(newnames)
```